# Export only selected columns in php

Tags: php, export

Previously it was hardcoded, but now the requirement is that I want to download only the selected columns.

**In View:**

```
foreach ($allColumnsDBArray as $colHeading) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class='form' name="selectedcols[]" value="<?php echo "$colHeading"; ?>" />
    <?php echo $colHeading; echo "<br>";
}
```

**In Controller:**

```
public function actionExport_csv() {
    $model = new Companies();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;             
    if(isset($_POST['download'])){ if(!empty($_POST['selectedcols'])) {
        foreach($_POST['selectedcols'] as $check) {
            echo $check;//what will be the code here to download column in selectedcols
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where's Yii code in this? I can see only plain PHP code. Have you used any widget for export?

Comment: excelview widget is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use export menu widget to export selected columns